# Where does an output file go?

Tags: c, file-io, output

If you have a program that writes to an output file in C, how do you access/see that output file? For instance, I'm trying to write a program that writes the values from a .ppm image file to another .ppm image file, but I don't know how to access the output file after I've done so. I know that's a pretty general question, but I don't have a block of code I can share just yet.

Comment: Use a full path name for the output file: then you know where is will be put.

Comment: How do you access your C source code? The executable? Your output file should be near (in the same folder of) those files... and can be accessed pretty much the same way.

Comment: When you create and save a file with a text editor, where does it go, and how would you access it afterwards? If you can answer that, you can answer your own question. (But you probably wouldn't use a text editor to access an image file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a file with `fopen` by only specifying a file name, without specifying a path, then the file will be put in the current working directory of your program.

If you are using an [integrated development environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (IDE) to launch your program, then you can probably see and set your program's initial working directory in your IDE. If you are running your program directly from a [command-line shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)#Command-line_shells), then the file will be placed in the current working directory of the shell.

On most operating systems, you can also determine your program's current working directory by calling a certain function provided by the operating system. For example, on POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux, you can call [`getcwd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3p.html). On Microsoft Windows, you can call [`_getcwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getcwd-wgetcwd?view=msvc-170) or [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory). That way, you should easily be able to find out in which directory your file is being created.